# Result is not being returned as a decimal

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet:

```
int main()
{
  int x, R, m;
  double Y, D, P;

  cout << "Enter investment: ";
  cin >> x;

  cout << "Enter rate per year: ";
  cin >> R;

  cout << "Enter months: ";
  cin >> m;

  /* Convert to years. */
  Y = m / 12;

  D = x * pow ((1 + (R/100)), Y);

  P = D - x;

  cout << "Investment after " << Y << " years is " << D << " bucks.\n";
  cout << "Profit is " << Y << " year(s) is " << P << " bucks.\n";
```

My result of cout is not being calculated properly and for some reason I'm not getting a decimal in the result.

I suspect it has something to do with the datatypes.

Comment: Define "not being calculated properly". What *are* you getting in the result?

Comment: you expect that `x * pow((1 + (R/100), Y)` yields a decimal value...?!? You might want to have a look at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Of course, even trivial math knowledge should lead you to see that the result of `pow(x, y)` for fractional values `x` and `y` will have funny result.

Comment: Fixed-point arithmetic is better: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/rational/cpp_rational.html

Comment: The year is returning "0" and the investment after Y years is the same as the input. Profit is calculated to be "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D = x * pow ((1 + (R/100)), Y);
```

`R/100` will result in an integer since both operands are ints. At least one of them must be `double` for it to work.

```
D = x * pow ((1 + (R/100.0)), Y);
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried this before you answered and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make at least one of operand to double  to make it work.

```
  Y = m / 12.;

  D = x * pow ((1 + (R/100.)), Y);
```